# how to resort the $a by bestsort config array?

Tags: php

how to resort the $a by bestsort config array?
if there are sort keys in $best_sort , the items in $a must be placed first ,
if no sort keys in $best_sort ,the items keeps the original sort order.

```
<?php

$a=array(
    'pn=1',
    'pp=20',
    'filter=price',
    'sub_cPath=1',
    'type=2'
);

$best_sort=array(
    'sub_cPath',
    'pn',
    'pp',
    'date'
);

function my_sort(){
    // how to resort the $a by $best sort?
    // the result should be bellow
}

$result=array(
    'sub_cPath=1',
    'pn=1',
    'pp=20',

    'filter=price',
    'type=2'
);

?>
```

Comment: What's the logic here?

Comment: Why does it matter what order those string keys are in the array? If you're dealing with string keys, you don't generally care what order they're defined in the array.